# Putting a json object into mongoose model withour getting .save is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

At the top I have this:

```
var invoiceModel = require('../../models/invoiceModel');
var invoiceRecord = new invoiceModel();
```

This is all good and if I fill out the invoice fields one by one it works.

```
invoiceRecord.dueDate = someDate
invoiceRecord.amount = someAmount
etc..
invoiceRecord.save(function (err, res) {
etc..
```

But!  I get the whole record structure from `req.body`
And when I do this:

```
invoiceRecord = req.body.invoice
```

Then my `invoiceRecord.save` will give this error

```
TypeError: invoiceRecord.save is not a function
```

I understand its because even thou I define `invoiceRecord` as a model, it is overwritten by `req.body.invoice` and become an object.

If my only way to move the fields one by one (cause I got a lot of fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do it like this:

```
var invoiceRecord = new invoiceModel(req.body.invoice)
```

But make sure that the key names of object are same as the key names in mongoose. Eg: If you have your object like: `{name: 'Kamesh'}` then your mongoose model should have the field 'name' in it's model. So whenever you pass in the whole object, mongoose will know which value to put into which field in its database.

Comment: Damnit!! hehe I didnt know you could do that. Makes sense thou, thanks :)